# Burninate the sorting-hat (sub-tag of Harry Potter) tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Inspired by [Why didn't Harry want to be placed in Slytherin?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/94181/24773)

Do we need a [sorting-hat](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting-hat) tag? Are there really specialists in sorting hat questions inside the harry potter specialists?

I motion for the burninating of that tag.

Comment: On reflection, it doesn't seem an obvious candidate for deletion

Comment: It is funny how this sub does not have a [meta-tag:burninate] meta tag.

Comment: @Mindwin “burninate” refers to a special (staff-only?) function that purges the tags from all questions, in a single go. It’s useful on sites like Stack Overflow, where a bad tag may run to thousands of questions, but we don’t have the sort of scale that needs burnination. If a tag is rotten, it’s usually small enough that it can be deleted through editing by high-rep users.

Answer (score 4):

**I think we should keep it.**

Several reasons why I think it’s an okay tag:

- It’s not ambiguous. The Sorting Hat – or Sorting in general – are fairly well-defined within the scope of the Potterverse. It’s not too ambiguous or obscure to be not useful.
- I think the tag is useful. We have a fair number of “Why was X sorted into Y” questions, but also other mechanics about the Sorting Hat. It’s a well-defined category that I think would be difficult to search for without the tag. I have used it in a couple of searches.
- Are there specialists in the Sorting Hat? I don’t know, but I also don’t think that the lack of specialists means we have to get rid of it. It’s being applied to questions, it’s well-scoped and it describes a major theme in the universe. That seems like a good tag.

  I’m not convinced that we should do anything except leave it be.

*(Mild disclaimer: I’m the second highest user in the tag, and my most upvoted answer is also in the tag.)*

Comment: I think we should keep the Sorting Hat tag, as well. For example, one of the Sorting Hat questions (*Could the Sorting Hat have told Dumbledore that Harry was a Horcrux*) actually contains some fairly critical information regarding Harry's status as a Horcrux. I think it's an important tag and should be left intact. :)